# Phaser 3/JavaScript load external webpage to new window/scene/canvas

Tags: javascript, iframe, phaser-framework

is it possible to pop a window-like scene to load a web-page (maybe iFrame)? For example, if I need an in-app pop-up window (not new pop un browser windows or redirect) to load a Youtube/Twitch Live Streams, or an External Sponsorship page that loads on the game/apps. I don't see any tutorials on Google.

Comment: Maybe an html page is enough? (Obviously you can have anything in that).

https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/loader/html/load-html-to-texture

Comment: I mean, for example, I want to load a certain youtube video (URL) on the phaser frame, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can load almost any kind of html inside Phaser using [DOMElement](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement.html).

So you can even load an iFrame as in the following code.

```js
function create() {
  this.add.dom(350, 250)
    .createFromHTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/crgzg0X0ZyA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}

var game = new Phaser.Game({
  parent: "gameDiv",
  dom: { createContainer: true },
  scene: { create },
  width: 700,
  height: 500,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.52.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<div id="gameDiv"></div>
```

If the iFrame doesn't work here on StackOverflow, try on CodePen: https://codepen.io/ildede/pen/BaQYarG